# BindBuffer and BufferData called back to back

Tags: graphics, opengl-es, webgl

In OpenGL ES (or in my case, WebGL), I don't see how binding vertex and color buffers back to back and then calling drawArrays works. For instance, here is some example code for you to get the idea:

```
vertexBuffer = glCreateBuffer();
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertextBuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

colorBuffer = glCreateBuffer();
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colorBuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colors, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, numberOfVertices);
```

If I bind GL_ARRAY_BUFFER to first the vertices, bufferData, and then go and bind some colors, what is going on behind the scenes there? It somehow seems to me like the vertex information should be ignored because I bound color information to GL_ARRAY_BUFFER right after it.

Comment: Actually, if this is the entirety of your code, then it does not work, because you have not setup any vertex array pointers.

Comment: yes, the point about opengl i was missing was the assignment of the vertex attribute, which @derhass explained. sorry for the bad example (now that i know what i was misunderstanding).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`glDrawArrays()` does not care what `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` is bound at all. It does care about the vertex attrib pointers.

What really matters here is not shown in the code you pasted: the attribute pointer setup. The reference to the currently bound `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` will become part of the attrib pointer when `glVertexAttribPointer()` is called. Different attributes can come from different VBOs, or you can use one VBO as a source for may attributes, that is completely up to you.

Comment: ah okay, i think i get it now. its like GL_ARRAY_BUFFER is just a global variable that is used in the implementation of glVertextAttribPointer. if i were to do what i did in my example, but not call glVertexAttribPointer, then it wouldnt work because the GL_ARRAY_BUFFER wouldve been overwritten before being assigned to a shader attribute via glVertexAttribPointer.

Comment: Well. The `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` binding is part of the GL _state_, and indeed a global one (wrt. the GL context). And yes, this state is relevant when setting the vertex attrib pointers. It is also relevant for some other things, especially any GL function operation with buffers when the `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` target is used.

Answer (score 6):

`gl.vertexAttribPointer` is what actually sets which attributes use which buffers.

You can think of it as

```
gl = { 
   arrayBuffer: someBuffer, 
   vertexArray: {
     elementArrayBuffer: someOtherBuffer,
     attributes: [], 
   },
};
```

When you call `gl.bindBuffer` you're just setting one of 2 global variables in the gl state.

```
gl.bindBuffer = function(bindPoint, buffer) {
   switch (bindPoint) {
      case: this.ARRAY_BUFFER:
         this.arrayBuffer = buffer;
         break;
      case: this.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER:
         this.vertexArray.elementArrayBuffer = buffer;
         break;
   }
};
```

When you call `gl.vertexAttribPointer` it copies current value of `arrayBuffer` to the specified attribute.

```
gl.vertexAttribPointer = function(index, size, type, normalized, stride, offset) {
    var attribute = this.vertexArray.attributes[index];
    attribute.size = size;
    attribute.type = type;
    attribute.normalized = normalized;
    attribute.stride = stride;
    attribute.offset = offset;
    attribute.buffer = this.arrayBuffer;  // copies the current buffer reference.
};
```

Textures work similarly except there's only 1 global variable

```
gl = { 
    activeTextureUnit: 0,
    textureUnits: [], 
};
```

`gl.activeTexture` sets which texture unit you're working on.

```
gl.activeTexture = function(unit) {
   this.activeTextureUnit = unit - this.TEXTURE_0;  // make it zero based.
};
```

Every texture unit has both a `TEXTURE_2D` and a `TEXTURE_CUBEMAP` so `gl.bindTexture(b, t)` is effectively

```
gl.bindTexture = function(bindPoint, texture) {
   var textureUnit = this.textureUnits[this.activeTextureUnit];
   switch (bindPoint) {
       case this.TEXTURE_2D:
           textureUnit.texture2D = texture;
           break;
       case this.TEXTURE_CUBEMAP:
           textureUnit.textureCubeMap = texture;
           break;
   }
};
```

Here is a [webgl state diagram](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/resources/webgl-state-diagram.html)

Comment: this is what i visualized in my head based on the previous answer, but thank you very much for writing it out!

Comment: @gman so does this mean that if the poster wanted to set color and vertex attributes (which I think he wanted to do) he would have to make a call to `gl.vertexAttribPointer` and a call to `gl.enableVertexAttribArray` in between the calls to `gl.bindBuffer`?

Comment: The short answer is **yes**. http://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-drawing-multiple-things.html

Comment: I think this is a tremendous answer.